# Is it possible to have infinite loop Thread and JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, jframe, infinite

I am trying to create some little game where in one Thread is running an Infinite Loop that is going to do Engine job and in JFrame is going to be all stuff that is Outputed on screen.

But I am facing one big problem that I am unable to fix and also not finding any answer on the internet. When I have no immediate output to console in infinite loop in my Thread then it seem like That Thread (in Engine class) is killed by Program and leaving me with JFrame only. But when there is some output to console in infinite loop then Thread (in Engine class) is fully working as expected to do and that is driving me crazy :(

Main CLASS:

```
package ccarsimulator;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CCarSimulator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Window window = new Window("CCarsimulator");
        });
    }        
}
```

Window CLASS:

```
package ccarsimulator;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Window extends JFrame{
    Engine oEngine = new Engine(this);


    JLabel LabelOutput = new JLabel();

    JPanel PanelCanvas = new JPanel();

    JLabel LabelSpeed;
    JLabel LabelRPM;
    JLabel LabelGearSet;
    JLabel LabelTotalTime;
    JLabel LabelFPS;
    JLabel LabelCPS;

    public Window(String WindowTitle){
        super(WindowTitle);

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent oKey) {
                System.out.println("Key Pressed");
                oEngine.bKeyPressed[oKey.getKeyCode()] = true;
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent oKey) {
                oEngine.bKeyPressed[oKey.getKeyCode()] = false;
            }
        });
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent oEvent){
                System.out.println("Closing a Window");
                oEngine.bStopEngine = true;
            }
        });

        this.add(PanelCanvas);
        PanelCanvas.add(LabelOutput);
        LabelOutput.setText("Test");

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Engine CLASS:

```
package ccarsimulator;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Engine extends Thread{
    Thread thisSelf = this;
    public boolean bStopEngine = false;
    public Window oWindow;

    public boolean []bKeyPressed = new boolean[KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED + 1];
    public boolean []bKeyReleased = new boolean[KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED + 1];

    public Engine(Window oWindow){
        this.oWindow = oWindow;
        thisSelf.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Waiting for window");
        //while(!oWindow.isVisible() && !bStopEngine);
        System.out.println("Engine is up and Running");
        while(!bStopEngine){
            //
            //---------------------------------------
            //Add some output to console to make this loop working...
            //---------------------------------------
            //
            if(bKeyPressed[KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE]){
                System.out.println("Pressed Escape");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Engine was disabled");
    }
}
```

Result without some output to console in Engine's class Thread infinite loop is

```
Waiting for window
Engine is up and Running
Key Pressed
Key Pressed
Key Pressed
Key Pressed
Closing a Window
```

Result with some output is:

```
Waiting for window
Engine is up and Running
Some debug
Some debug
...
...
Some debug
Closing a Window
Some debug
Some debug
Engine was disabled
```

Comment: Guys please instead down voting this thread just explain me what I am doing wrong... Or explain why you are down voting this thread... Because it is not fair from your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, My Java Guru friend helped me to figure this all out.
And also answered my question why this got disliked in few seconds as I published this Question what I still find unfair because I couldn't describe it much clear, If I did I would find answer on my problem without asking.

Problem was that I had to add `volatile` keyword on variables these were handled by Two threads (My Engine thread and Swing thread).

Without keyword `volatile` I was experiencing that my Swing thread was changing these two Engine thread's (`bStopEngine` and `bKeyPressed`) variables in RAM memory while these two Engine thread's variables were in CPU Cache memory so Engine thread could not know something changed because these two variables were not changed at right place.

Also helped me understand why my code works with only setting one of these two variables with volatile. It is because Java should by default load about 4KB block of memory page into CPU memory. So if by any luck my volatile variable gets into this page with another used variable by Swing Thread without using volatile keyword then that page is still set on thread synchronization and still synchronizing my variables with Swing thread so that is why it still works.

Just telling to help other people in future to rid off their confusions with similar problem or for myself in future when I once again forget all of this ;)